How to know that the kernel of a vector bundle morphism is complemented
I am analyzing a proof that involves vector bundles and there is a part of it that is not clear to me and I would like to ask about it.
Let $g\in \mathcal{M}=\{g\in Met^{k,\alpha}(M):\int_{M}v_{g}=1\}$, where $v_{g}$ is the form of volume in the manifold $M$.
Let $\mathcal{D}_{g}=\{\phi*g:\phi\in C^{k,\alpha}(M):\int_{M}\phi v_{g}=0\}$. Then $\mathcal{D}=\bigcup_{g\in \mathcal{M}}\mathcal{D}_{g}$ is a smooth integrable distribution on $\mathcal{M}.$
Proof: This is proven by showing that $\mathcal{D}$ is the image of a smooth vector bundle morphism with constant rank. Consider the trivial vector bundles (over $\mathcal{M}$) $E_{1}=\mathcal{M}\times C^{k,\alpha}(M)$, $E_{2}=\mathcal{M}\times \mathbb{R}$ and the smooth vector bundle morphism $f_{1}:E_{1}\longrightarrow E_{2}$ definided by $$f_{1}(g,\phi)=(g,\int_{M}\phi v_{g}).$$  Clearly , $f_{1}$ is surjective, and its kernel $$E_{3}=\bigcup_{g\in \mathcal{M}}\{g\}\times\{\phi\in C^{k,\alpha}(M):\int_{M}\phi v_{g}=0\},$$ which is closed and complemented, is a smooth vector subbundle of $E_{1}$.
How do I justify the claim that $E_{3}$ is closed and complemented?
